# How to convert filled HTML view to PDF using snappy/wkhtmltopdf in controller or in View?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am beginner to laravel, i have a blade view when it'll be filled and clicked on the submit button then need to download this filled form in pdf. Currently i am able to download pdf through URL (http://www.bing.com) but how to download filled view please help. I am using Laravel version 5.3.10. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am having great time working with pdf files. This is not related to the one you used but maybe this can help you.

https://github.com/thujohn/pdf-l4

Comment: Thanks kapa for your reply. You have worked a lot with pdf files as you said, could you please guide me about any package in laravel/php that can solve my problem. Thanks in advance.